# Using CMD to produce txt file list of all files in a directory but Sequentially

Tags: sorting, cmd, sequential

I have found that the following puts the file names in a text document but with no identifiable sorting.

```bash
dir /b "*.mp4" > files
for "tokens=*" %%i in (files) do move "%%i" !random!.mp4
```

I would want them sequential from a list such as this:

```
i_ch3_main_20230401030500_20230401030600.mp4
i_ch3_main_20230401004900_20230401005000.mp4
i_ch3_main_20230401023700_20230401023800.mp4
i_ch3_main_20230401050900_20230401051000.mp4
i_ch3_main_20230401040900_20230401041000.mp4
```

So the second one on this list would actually go first, and the 2nd to last would be last etc. (these are 2023, April, 1st, and then military time to explain how it would be sequentially.

My problem is I don't want 5:09 AM showing before 4:09 AM etc.). I can't find a suitable CMD answer to this.

Also I want to plug this into `ffmpeg` concat, so is there a way to add the required "file" to each line of the text document within the code?

Comment: See what `dir /?` tells you about sorting (it's the `/o` option. For example `dir /os` will sort by size (smallest first), while `dir /o-s` will sort biggest first. There are several other options, including by name. I don't get though why the sorting is of any importance when you are renaming them to random names anyway

Comment: Thank you Stephan and Mofi!  Mofi the dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON >ListOrderedByName.txt works perfectly, this solves it except also is there a way to insert "file" in front of each line of text (so I can concat in ffmpeg, it seems ffmpeg gives errors unless the concat text doc reads "file" for each line)   Stephan, not needing to rename files per se but the addition of "file" might have the same solution as partial rename.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions per submission. The above comments have handled your main issue.

Comment: `... do move "%%i" "file-%%~nxi"` See `for /?` for an explanation of those `%%~` modifiers.

Comment: @RayRay There can be used a `for /F` loop to customize the data written into the file, i.e. `(for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do @echo file "%I")>ListOrderedByName.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method in PowerShell which should achieve that for you:

1. Open PowerShell in the directory containing the .mp4 files.
2. Enter this command to generate the list:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp4 | Sort-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[3]} | ForEach-Object {"file '$($_.FullName)'" } > files.txt
```

Here's what it does:

- `Get-ChildItem *.mp4` gets a list of all .mp4 files in the current directory.
- `Sort-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[3]}` sorts the files based on the 4th section of the file name (starting from 0) which is the timestamp you are interested in.
- `ForEach-Object {"file '$($_.FullName)'" }` prefixes each file name with "file" and includes the full file path.
- `> files.txt` outputs the list to a file named files.txt.

After you've done this, you should have a file called "files.txt" in the same directory, with each line looking something like this:

```
file 'C:\path\to\i_ch3_main_20230401004900_20230401005000.mp4'
file 'C:\path\to\i_ch3_main_20230401023700_20230401023800.mp4'
file 'C:\path\to\i_ch3_main_20230401030500_20230401030600.mp4'
file 'C:\path\to\i_ch3_main_20230401040900_20230401041000.mp4'
file 'C:\path\to\i_ch3_main_20230401050900_20230401051000.mp4'
```

These can be directly used in ffmpeg concat.

Comment: Thanks Sash Sinha,  How do I not have the full file path though?  ffmpeg concat works without the full file path for me.  Please help. I have played around with this code in Powershell, by dropping the .Fullname and $ and combinations but no luck.  Everything else works great!